# Reg Exp optimisation

Tags: .net, regex, optimization

I need to optimise the following reg exp so that it executes faster. Can anyone help?

```
([\d\w]{15}[\x01]\d{12}[\x01]\d{2}(.){6}((13((0[0-9]|([1-4][0-9])|5[0-9]))|14((0[0-9]|([1-2][0-9])|30)))[0-5][0-9])801(?:.*))
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code that you are using as well.

Comment: I would think the any speed you get from optimizing the regex will be minimal, if any at all. Are you sure you have a bottle neck with your regex?

Comment: `[\d\w]` is redundant. `\w` implies `\d`. Replacing your initial `[\d\w]` with `\w` could have a fairly large effect on the runtime. Also, if you don't need the individual capture groups, then specify `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` in the options parameter.

Comment: @Jim: I would be very surprised if `[\d\w]` turned out to be any slower than `\w`.  It's effectively the union of the two sets represented by `\d` and `\w`; no character should get checked more than once.  You're probably thinking of `(?:\d|\w)`; now that's a major performance killer.

Comment: @Alan: Actually, I was thinking of the needless character class. That is, `[\d\w]` might very well become `[\w]`, but as I recall (and I could be wrong), that somehow doesn't get optimized to `\w`. I remember some years ago that `[\w]` matched much more slowly than `\w`. Memory is faulty, of course, and maybe it wasn't even the .NET regex class that exhibited this behavior.

Comment: @Jim: If any regex flavor ever behaved that way, I'd say it was the result of a bug.  Maybe you're thinking about `(?:.|\s)`, a very common but misguided pattern for "everything including newlines".

Answer (score 3):

This is an optimized version: removed a lot of redundant character classes and groups. Ultimately it would be better to know what the regex is supposed to do.

```
\w{15}\x01\d{12}\x01\d{2}.{6}(13[0-5]\d|14([0-2]\d|30))[0-5]\d801.*
```

Edit: based on your new information, you can reduce it further down to:

```
\w{15}\x01\d{12}\x01\d{2}.{6}(13[0-5]\d|1400)[0-5]\d801.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you want your regex to do it's hard to optimise it, but you could try passing [RegexOptions.Compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) to the Regex constructor. This will take longer to construct the regex object but will mean it performs it's searches more quickly.

Comment: `RegexOptions.Compiled` is not a panacea.  Depending on how the regex is being used, this could make the performance much worse.

Answer (score 0):

The reg exp searches in a text file for records who have the following format and values:

The record should start with 15 digits or characters, followed by a special character `[\x01]` followed by 12 digits and `[\x01]` again, followed by 2 digits and any 6 characters, then look for values (date values in the format Hours Minutes Seconds without any `:` or `.` separating the hours and minutes and seconds in the file) between 130000 and 140059 which is the part of the reg exp I extracted below, and lastly the value 801 and any number of characters that may follow.

```
((13((0[0-9]|([1-4][0-9])|5[0-9]))|14((0[0-9]|([1-2][0-9])|30)))[0-5][0-9])
```

Hope I have been clear and understandable here.

Also I added a ^ at the start of the reg exp and $ for the end.

I used the RegexOptions.Compiled options as well but not much improvement.

Thanks for all the tips, I will try them out. In the meantime if you have any more optimizations to suggest, be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry, a mistake on my part
The time part is between 130000 and 143059
I will try out your solution, bluepnume.